# Aggregating over random subsets of n rows of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to aggregate over random subsets of a python data frame with n rows. My current approach is to loop through rows and assign a "group id" in a new column then aggregate on this column, but my data frame has hundreds of thousands of rows and this is much too slow. What is a more efficient way to do this?

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': rand.randn(300000), 'column2': rand.rand(300000)})
df['groupid'] = 0
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) #randomize dataframe rows
group_size = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
for size in group_size:
        group_num = 0
        for position in range(0, len(df), size):
            df.iloc[position:position + size, df.columns.get_loc('groupid')] =  group_num
            group_num+=1

        results = df.groupby(['groupid'], as_index=True).agg({'column1': 'mean', 'column2': 'mean'})
```

Edit: I need to use every row of data exactly once. The output should be a dataframe with each row giving the average of column1 and column2 for each group (such that `results.shape[0] = np.ceil(df.shape[0]/size)`)

**Update:**
I was able to quickly achieve the desired behavior by first randomizing the data frame then using itertools to generate a list with repeated sequential numbers:

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': rand.randn(300000), 'column2': rand.rand(300000)})
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) #randomize dataframe rows
group_size = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
for size in group_size:
        df['groupid'] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, size) for x in range(int(np.ceil(df.shape[0]/size)))))[0:df.shape[0]]
        results = df.groupby(['groupid'], as_index=True).agg({'column1': 'mean', 'column2': 'mean'})
```

Comment: Can you share a reprodudcible example with sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.random.shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) function to shuffle an array at random:

```py
n = df.shape[0]
for gs in group_size:

    a = np.hstack([np.repeat(np.arange(gs), n//gs), np.arange(n%gs)]) 
    np.random.shuffle(a)

    df[f'group_size_{gs}'] = a
```

Remark that `np.random.shuffle` modifies the array in-place.

Comment: This does not seem to guarantee that the groups will be equal size.

Comment: @Kyle You are right, that was a fast shortcut. I edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a sampling method built in.

```
df = df.sample(n=10)
```

This returns a dataframe comprised of 10 randomly sampled rows of df. No need to groupby, just aggregate on this.

Comment: Per my edit, I need to use each row exactly once so I don't believe this will work.